# how to reference the value of an input element using angular event handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, reference

how I do :

```
<input ng-keyup="foo($event)">

$scope.foo = function (event) {
  var v = event.srcElement.value;
}
```

how I want to do :

```
<input ng-keyup="foo(this.value);">

$scope.foo = function (v) {
  var v = v;
}
```

this doesn't work. `this` doesn't reference to the input element.

Answer (score 1):

For all the `ng-` events(or other directives) types `this` means the scope with which the DOM is compiled.

Bind the input's value to a model and use in your event handler.

```
<input ng-model="myModel" ng-keyup="foo()">
```

**In Controller**

```
$scope.foo = function () {
    //use $scope.myModel
}
```

If you don't want to bind the input to a model, the solution which you are using currently is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the value of the input to the `$scope` using `ng-model` and either pass that value in as a parameter to `foo` or you can reference it directly in the definition of `$scope.foo`.

Comment: thanks for your support but I am not trying to bind anything.

Comment: However, consider the update of my post, the foo function is in the scope.

Comment: If you share more code it can be clearer what you are trying to do, but in general scopes are designed to serve as the single source of your model.